# how to validate string condition as valid syntax Condition

Tags: vb.net, validation, syntax

i am trying to make user generate Rule (Condition ) like this 
" Result >85" and Result is a keyword which i will replace  with specific value 
how to make sure that rule that user has generate is correct as a syntax 
becuse i'll take the generated rule and put it in if condition so it have to be correct as syntax
my final result should like this 
if user rule like  "Result >85 " show message that rule can be Applied

if user rule like "Result And >85 " show message that rule can not be Applied

- used language is VB .net

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: i am using Vb .net

Comment: i have found the solution :   Dim objExpression As New NCalc.Expression(RuleGenerated)
        If Not objExpression.HasErrors Then
            ShowErrorMessage(lblErrMsg, "Success ")
        Else
            ShowErrorMessage(lblErrMsg, "Failed ")
        End If

Comment: When posting questions, you should add a tag for the language you're using. You should also post your answer below and accept it when you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution For the  issue :

```
Dim objExpression As New NCalc.Expression(RuleGenerated)
If Not objExpression.HasErrors Then
ShowErrorMessage(lblErrMsg, "Success ")
Else 
ShowErrorMessage(lblErrMsg, "Failed ") 
End If
```